# Why does TCPview show both TCP and UDP for this Java socket program?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm running the standard Java networking [example from Oracles site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)  , and it runs a simple Knock-knock joke program. This creates teh standard sockets, which I believe are TCP connections(or am i wrong here? ) .

What's confusing me is that when I view the ports in [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) , what is see is that there are multiple lines  showing for port 4444 (the one we connect to with the Knock-Knock program). Here's a screenshot( [full image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNjRS.png) ):
[image]

Why does it show both UDP and TCP ? Shouldn't it only be TCP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the sample code is using **UDP** on port 4444. Your TCPView also shows that it's another process (different PID) that is using the **UDP** port:

[image]

Also, when I run the sample code, I only see the **TCP** records:

[image]

My guess is that you might have another sample running with a DatagramSocket ?! You might verify that the sample code is not the one using the **UDP** ports, by changing it to use a different port. Try e.g. changing the port to 5555 in the **KnockKnockServer**:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 5555.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

and in the **KnockKnockClient**:

```
    try {
        kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
        out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
```

and see if you have any **UDP** records on this port.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different processes there. Any chance you have a stale process running the udp demo hanging around?